# MATLAB: Compare data from imfindcircles to data from bwconncomp

Tags: matlab, image-processing

**WARNING** - Complete n00b here.

I'm working on a project which needs to find holes.  I found a method that is fairly accurate (`bwconncomp`) but I get some extra data that I don't need (a.k.a holes that aren't holes).  Now the holes are circular so I was just going to do a check with `imfindcircles`.

So what I need to do is take the center coordinate and radius info from `imfindcircles` to filter out the non-circular holes in `bwconncomp`.  How should I tackle that?

```
%Find Circles
[centersDark, radiiDark] = imfindcircles(im,[10 75],'ObjectPolarity','dark');

%Find holes (I think)
cc = bwconncomp(BW);

%Put box around holes (prints to figure for debugging... kinda)
rp = regionprops(cc,'BoundingBox');
```

So just to clarify, I need to figure out how to weed out the extra info in `cc` from the data received in from `imfindcircles` (those variables being `centersDark` and `radiiDark`)

Here's a sample image:[image: Here's a sample image:]

Comment: can you post a sample image?

Comment: @Benoit_11 added edit

Comment: I don't have access to the image processing toolbox right now, but you should be able to check if one of `centersDark` is in `cc.PixelIdxList{ii}` for each `ii`, though I think you'll have to turn `centersDark` into indices first.

Comment: I don't have access to it right now either but I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can also improve your segmentation stage:

```
close all;
% read input
im = imread('holes.bmp');
grayImg = rgb2gray(im);

% create an image where holes are removed
med = medfilt2(grayImg,[100,100],'symmetric');

figure();
imshow(med);
title('median');

% subtract image with holes from image without holes
% so the whole process is less dependent on ilumination of foreground
diff = double(med) - double(BW);

figure();
imshow(uint8(diff+127));
title('difference');

% apply threshold
bw = diff > 50;

figure();
imshow(bw);
title('threshold');

% remove small objects
SE = strel('disk',10);
opened = imopen(bw,SE);

figure();
imshow(opened);
title('imopen');

% get bounding boxes for each hole
cc = bwconncomp(opened);
rp = regionprops(cc,'BoundingBox');

% draw rectangles
figure();
imshow(im);
hold on;
title('result');
for i = 1:length(rp)
    rectangle('Position',rp(i).BoundingBox,'EdgeColor','red')
end
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'm actually converting to grayscale and I do enclose it with a box, I just posted relevant code and specified my problem.